# C program can only write to file when given absolute path and cant when given relative path

Tags: c, linux

I am running this on `linux-mint`. In this simple code, I'm trying to write to a file name `input.txt` which is in the same directory as this script is in. When I give the relative path (e.g. only `input.txt` as the path to the file), nothing is written to the file, but when I give the absolute path the program works. I am able to make `"hello world"` write to `input.txt`.

I don't understand what the difference is:

```cpp
#include <zconf.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main() {
    close(1);
    open("/home/maor/CLionProjects/untitled2/input.txt", O_RDWR );
    if (fork() == 0) {
        int fd = dup(1);
        write(fd, "hello ", 6);
    } else {
        wait(0);
        write(1, "world\n ", 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: The base for relative paths is not the directory the program is in but the working directory of the process executing the program, which is typically the working directory of the command-line shell used to execute the program,

Comment: Path relative to.......what?  Some 'current directory' that may, or may not, be where you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

> The base for relative paths is not the directory the program is in but the 
>   working directory of the process executing the program, which is typically the
>   working directory of the command-line shell used to execute the program

Eric answer solved this issue.